# Windows Advanced Firewall certificate based IPSEC

Tags: windows, ipsec

I'm working on migrating from using IPSEC settings stored under the 'IP Security Policies on Active Directory' to using the 'Windows Firewall with Advanced Security' for my 2008+ boxes.

I have successfully been able to get this set up using Kerberos authentication, however my openswan implementation on my Linux boxes is using certificates. Whenever I try changing the authentication method to computer certificate (using RSA and my root CA) the connection is bombing out.

I've made this change at both a connection request policy and on the IPSEC settings on the root Windows Firewall with Advanced Security node. The windows event log shows the authentication request is taking place but failing negotiating a mode.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a couple weeks of testing I finally got this down to needing to check the "Enable certificate to Account Mapping" checkbox on my connection security rule.