# Windows Firewall Connection Security with Certificate (2)

Tags: certificate, ipsec

I have a similar problem as the question with the [same title](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71434/windows-firewall-connection-security-with-certificate?rq=1) from last October.

On a Windows Server 2008 machine, using Windows Firewall's Connection Security rules, I need to establish an IPsec transport mode connection to another server 2008 using certificates for authentication.

I can establish a certificate based IPsec connection using the security policy setting in the local group policy, however the encryption settings are insufficient for the security environment it will be used in. I can also establish a pre-shared key based IPsec connection with Window Firewall, but it fails when I switch to certificates.

The error in the Windows Event Log says "IKE failed to find valid machine certificate". Based on this [Technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737812(v=ws.10).aspx) , my certs are valid, and I have made sure their root CA is on the machine as well.

The CAPI2 (crypto API) log is enabled and set to verbose mode, but doesn't show any errors. From its logs, it seems to check the cert chain over and over, without showing any errors.

The cert has KeyUsage for digital signature, key encipherment, and non-repudiation. The EKUs are server auth, client auth, and IKE intermediate. I have turned off CRL checking temporarily, so I can rule that out.

Any idea why my cert is invalid and what I need to do to fix it?

Comment: What store does the certificate reside in for the system?  Have you enabled debug logging (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754714%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)?

Comment: Found this related [question](http://serverfault.com/questions/445952/windows-advanced-firewall-certificate-based-ipsec?rq=1). I have enabled certificate to account mapping, but it didn't help.  @user2320464, I have the certificate in Local Machine/Personal, and logging is enabled for IPsec and CAPI.

Comment: Since the cert is in the right location, it seems like there isn't a certificate that meets the requirements for IPsec. Check the certificate fields (OIDs, "Issued To", "Intended Purposes", etc.).

Comment: The OIDs and Key Usage fields determine what the cert can be used for, and they are set correctly. The only thing "unusual" about the cert is that the server isn't connected to a domain so the subject isn't an FQDN, just the server hostname. I don't know why this would be an issue though.